# How to access Name of dataframe row?

Tags: python, pandas

When exctracting a row from a dataframe and printing it, we get an attribute `Name`, that is the snippet below produces following output:

```
col_a    20
Name: 1, dtype: int64
```

```py
import pandas as pd
test = dict(col_a=[10, 20, 30, 40, 50])
df = pd.DataFrame(test)
row = df.iloc[2]
print(row)
```

So given a `row` of some dataframe, how can we access this attribute? It looks like it is an index but `row.index` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it is easier than I thought, we can access it using

```
row.name
```